# How can i add new roles in my fosuserbundle?

Tags: php, symfony, web, doctrine, fosuserbundle

i which that i can add new users role 
like this

```
    role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_RMI
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_RM
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_RMIS
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_RP
```

and add them access to same path

```
- { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN ROLE_RM ROLE_RP ROLE_RMIS ROLE_RMI }
```

and then in my controller , i specifie what role should have to use this function

for exemple , ROLE_RP can change users name , ROLE_ADMIN can add new users ......

can any one help me to do this

Comment: check symfony's ACLs

Comment: @Federico can you explain with simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can do something like that :

```
ROLE_RMI : ROLE_USER
ROLE_ADMIN : ROLE_USER
ROLE_RM : ROLE_USER
ROLE_RMIS : ROLE_USER
ROLE_RP : ROLE_USER
ROLE_MYROLES: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_RMI, ROLE_RM, ROLE_RMIS, ROLE_RP]
```

with :

```
- { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_MYROLES}
```

And after in controller :

```
  if($user->hasRole('ROLE_RP')){ 
    // change users name 
  } else if($user->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')){
    //do others things
  }
```

Note that u need to defined in your UserInterface  :

```
public function getRoles() {
    return array('ROLE_THAT_U_NEED'); 
}
```